# What type can be used for a parameter of a generic method that will not be invoked?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, contravariance

I am trying to define a method with a parameter that has a generic type, using unknown as the generic type because I don't need it: `function f(op: Operation<unknown>): void {...}`.
It does not work in every case, it does not work if Operation uses its generic type in a method signature.

If instead of a method having the generic Context in parameter I use directly a generic Context member, it compiles without errors.

Can someone explain why I can't use `unknown` if the generic is in the signature of a method?

I am trying to figure out why this sample does not compile:

```ts
export interface Operation<Context> {
    process: (context: Context) => void;
    //context: Context;
    n:number;
}

type MyContext = {
  info: string;
}

const op : Operation<MyContext> = {
  process: (context: MyContext) => { console.log("process",context.info); },
  //context: { info:"context.info" },
  n:42
}

function fGeneric<Context>(op: Operation<Context>): void {
     console.log("fGeneric", op.n);
}

console.log(fGeneric(op));

function fUnknown(op: Operation<unknown>): void {
     console.log("fUnknown", op.n);
}

console.log(fUnknown(op)); 
// Argument of type 'Operation<MyContext>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Operation<unknown>'.
//  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'MyContext'.
```

Commenting out `process` and uncommenting `context` compiles without error.

(Obviously this is a simplified example, boiled down to the minimum to exhibit the problem.)

playground :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeTDUxgQiQB4Bhc1EGAPjgG8AoODuMKCXAZz4AuOAApstUDGE0UkgJRwAvEwBuEBABMA3O04B6PeNn1pE+js5wkgpAFcAtgCM0OgL6tWMAJ5E4AWS8ZOnhFFl1kdAhhPhgoZABzNw8jGLgIMDhhQmJScgoAoMkmULYObl5gAWExMyl-QNqFZRY4FIgAG2AAOnaIeJEAInL+PgGAGiNgroiIOS04VzHdA0nJYWZEJEjBAdX6aa2IAYWljmsAFgAmVndWdFskbFykOHQAcWAkNARsalqGETpLJEKAkMiUQr0BhyYRqTRhSytch8DrdXr9AbvT7fbDjNJgLpIOY3ZLI1E9PoiLFfOLYQFgOTEu4PJ7g14AVSQAGskBAAO5IenAnLgigPHn8pDQ2HqDQIyxtToUjHoTkSgV49KE4m3RVoymq7m8gX0xlaIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bottom type instead of the top type.

`unknown` is the top type: it contains all possible values.  A function taking an argument of type `unknown` should accept any value whatsoever as the argument.  A function that only accepts values of *some* types cannot possibly conform to `(_: unknown) => void`; however, a function `(_: unknown) => void` will conform to `(_: T) => void` for any `T`.  So we have that `T` is a subtype of `unknown`, but on the other hand `(_: unknown) => void` is a subtype of `(_: T) => void`.  This situation is known as *contravariance*, and we say that the type constructor that takes `T` to a type of functions-that-take-a-`T` is *contravariant* in `T`.

In your case, since the definition of `Operation<T>` specifies a property with a type of functions taking `T`, `Operation<T>` is contravariant in `T` as well.  That means `Operation<unknown>` is a *subtype* of `Operation<T>` for any other `T`, *not* a supertype as you want.  (When you changed `Operation<T>` to include a property of type just `T`, it instead became *covariant* in `T`, which means the subtype relationship is *not* reversed.)

Instead, you can use `Operation<never>`:

```ts
export interface Operation<Context> {
    process: (context: Context) => void;
    n: number;
}

type MyContext = {
    info: string;
}

const op : Operation<MyContext> = {
    process: (context: MyContext) =>
        { console.log("process", context.info); },
    n: 42
}

function fNever(op: Operation<never>): void {
    console.log("fNever", op.n);
}

console.log(fNever(op));
```

The bottom type `never` contains no values and is a subtype of all types.  Because `Operation<T>` is contravariant in `T`, this means that `Operation<never>` is a supertype of all `Operation<T>`.  In plainer language, by taking an `Operation<never>`, you don’t require `process` to be callable with anything in particular, and in effect you promise you will never call `process` at all: because `never` contains no values, a function taking a `never` argument is uncallable.

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works if the field `context: Context` in `Operation` is commented out.

Comment: I assumed the covariant `context: Context` field was added only for testing purposes. But yes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass an `Operation<MyContext>` to a function with a parameter of type `Operation<unknown>`, because that function could try to do an illegal modification of that parameter. As in:

```js
function fUnknown(op: Operation<unknown>): void {
    const foo: unknown = "Mystery";
    op.context = foo;
    console.log("fUnknown", op.n);
}
```

You should probably do something like this instead:

```js
function fUnknown2<T extends unknown>(op: Operation<T>): void {
    const foo: unknown = "Mystery";
    /* Would cause "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'unknown' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'."
    op.context = foo; */
    console.log("fUnknown", op.n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it does not compile is that function parameters are contravariant and `Operation` uses the `Context` type parameter in a function parameter position.

When you pass `op` to `fUnknown`, `op` claims that it can only work with `MyContext`, but `fUnknown` requires that the `Operation` passed to it can work with anything, not only `MyContext`.

You can solve this in a number of ways:

- require `Operation<any>`: if you don't use the generic information at all in the function body or in the rest of the signature, it's a totally valid option
- require `Operation<MyContext>`: it's not very versatile
- require `Operation<T>` and let `T` be inferred: when you pass `op`, `T` becomes `MyContext`, and you can use the information that `T` is generic in the function body/signature